# how to install claws-mail rpm package?

Tags: centos

I want to install claws-mail into my centos7 with three different methods,all of them fails.

method1:intall directly

```
[root@localhost ~]#  yum install claws-email
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.pubyun.com
No package claws-email available.
```

method2:install from rpm package.
I have downloaded  claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm   from official web.

```
[root@localhost ~]#  rpm  -ivh  /root/Downloads/claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm    
 warning: /root/Downloads/claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 81b46521: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:      
    libcompface.so.1()(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64   
    libetpan.so.17()(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64   
    libgnutls.so.30()(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64   
    libgnutls.so.30(GNUTLS_3_4)(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64   
    liblockfile.so.1()(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64   
    libpisock.so.9()(64bit) is needed by claws-mail-3.12.0-1.fc24.x86_64
```

I want to install the depended package first.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y libcompface.so.1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.pubyun.com
No package libcompface.so.1 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y libcompface.so
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.pubyun.com
No package libcompface.so available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y libcompface
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.pubyun.com
No package libcompface available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

method3:install according the tutorial .

http://linuxpitstop.com/install-claws-mail-3-12-on-ubuntu-linux/

For Fedora:
    Once these dependencies have been installed, download the new version of Claws mail from following URL.

```
yum install -y libc6 libcairo2 libcompfaceg1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libenchant1c2a libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libice6 libldap-2.4-2 libpango1.0-0 libpisock9 libsm6 xdg-utils
No package  available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Maybe the problem is repo files?How to add repo in my centos7?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `yum` to install claws-email? It downloads the dependencies that go with this software:

`sudo yum install claws-email`

Just note that if that is not the correct program name, try:

`sudo yum install claw*`

Comment: have you test it in your centos7?

Comment: I don't have access to a machine at the moment to do so..